# Define a bound for generic type function Rust

Tags: generics, struct, rust, traits

```rust
pub async fn create<T: Serialize>(form: &mut T, COLLECTION_NAME: &str) -> Result<T, ServiceError> {
    let collection = db::get_collection(COLLECTION_NAME).await?;

    let mut doc = db::encode(&form).unwrap();
    collection.insert_one(doc, None).await?;
    find(form.id.as_ref().unwrap(), COLLECTION_NAME).await
}
```

I'm trying to define a generic function of Type T. When I try to access the field from 'form' which is of type T.

I get the following error:

```
no field `id` on type `&mut T`
```

```rust
pub struct Form {
    #[serde(rename = "_id")]
    pub id: Option<ObjectId>,
    pub name: String,
}
```

The generic type T will receive the following struct as a parameter.
There can be multiple structs with `id` field

Comment: There is no way to make a "has field" constraint. You have to define a getter in the trait. Why is this generic anyway?

Comment: The function will receive different structs as a parameter. All having the id field

Comment: How to define a getter in the trait?

Comment: I've read traits at least basics, but unable to find answer for this

Comment: A getter is just a function, does that help?

Comment: I know about getters. But the thing is I'll have multiple structs with id field. So, I am confused, how to define a trait with getter which works for every structs. Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps something like [this](https://gist.github.com/d8c8058ee6a01cf801fea1f27e563c9d) (obviously untested)

Comment: @trentcl Actually I don't have a single struct. I'll pass structs with different fields with `id` as a common field to the function input.

Comment: The trait requires the getter. Every struct must impl the trait and thus the getter.

Comment: I understand that @SebastianRedl Can you share some insights on where I can find the solution?

Comment: Yes, you need to implement `Id` for all the structs that you want to pass as `T`. Generics in Rust are not fancy macros like C++ templates; they are type checked at declaration. You can't claim to be generic over any `T` and then *assume* that `T` has an `id` field. If you *want* a fancy macro, consider writing an actual macro instead of a generic function.